# e.preventDefault() is not working in IE6

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6

`e.preventDefault()` is not working in my IE6. Could you please provide some code to make it work in IE too?

I am using this function not anchor tag but on an image tag, so whenever somebody clicks on an image he should be ablt o drag over the image

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `e.preventDefault()` in IE6. I know this, because I use it *extensively* throughout an app which has been tested in all browsers. Can you elaborate on 'not working in IE6'?

Comment: Are you passing it as formal parameter to your anonymous function? e.g. `function(e<--this here) { e.preventDefault() }`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393399/jquery-i-have-an-issue-when-drag-a-part-of-an-image-to-select-its-parts is my actual problem

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393399/jquery-i-have-an-issue-when-drag-a-part-of-an-image-to-select-its-parts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in place of `e.preventDefault()` you could also `return false;` at the end of the code like this,

```
$('a').click(function(){
   // other codes
   return false;
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393399/jquery-i-have-an-issue-when-drag-a-part-of-an-image-to-select-its-parts is my actual problem

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
return false;
```

instead of e.prevendefault();

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393399/jquery-i-have-an-issue-when-drag-a-part-of-an-image-to-select-its-parts is my actual problem

Answer (score 0):

Try adding e.stop() or returning false at the end of your function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393399/jquery-i-have-an-issue-when-drag-a-part-of-an-image-to-select-its-parts is my actual problem